# Find minimum value of conditional statement where condition is also met for all values after

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to identify the first value which is less than 1 and where all values following this element are also less than 1 and less than or equal to that value.

I have a DT:

```
stack <- data.table(a = as.numeric(seq(1,10,1)),
                b = as.numeric(c(1.54, 1.17, 0.75, 1.65, 0.61, 0.31, 0.90, 0.07, 0.04, 0.01)),
               ID = as.numeric(rep(seq(1,2,1),5)))

stack
     a    b ID
 1:  1 1.54  1
 2:  2 1.17  2
 3:  3 0.75  1
 4:  4 1.65  2
 5:  5 0.61  1
 6:  6 0.31  2
 7:  7 0.90  1
 8:  8 0.07  2
 9:  9 0.04  1
10: 10 0.01  2
```

The value I am looking for in this example would be row 7:

```
   a    b ID
7: 7 0.90  1
```

This is the first value less than 1 where all values following are less than 1 and are also less than or equal to that value. I am specifically interested in returning the value from column `a`.

I have tried `stack[,min(which(b < 1))]` but this is clearly missing the additional conditional requirements

Comment: @bouncyball, thanks for the catch. You are correct. Edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stack[which(b < 1 &
            sapply(seq_len(.N), 
                   function(i) all(b[min(.N, i + 1):nrow(stack)] <= b[i]))
            )[1]]
```

If `b[i] < 1` and `b[i + x] <= b[i]` we don't need to check if `b[i + x] < 1`

Or by `ID`

```
fun <- function(b){
  N <- length(b)
  which(b < 1 &
        sapply(seq_len(N), 
               function(i) all(b[min(N, i + 1):N] <= b[i]))
        )[1] == seq_len(N)
}

setorder(stack, ID)
stack[stack[, fun(b), by = ID]$V1]
```

**EDIT:**

I cannot delete this post since it has been accepted, but I have realized this gives an incorrect answer in many cases, e.g. the one below. The other answer is correct (and much faster anyway).

```
set.seed(0)
DT <- data.table(a=1:10, b=1.1*runif(10))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method:

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(0L)
M <- 1e4
DT <- data.table(a=1:M, b=10*runif(M))

mtd1 <- function() {
    DT[which(b < 1 &
            sapply(seq_len(.N), 
                function(i) all(b[min(.N, i + 1):nrow(DT)] <= b[i]))
    )[1]]   
}

mtd2 <- function() {
    DT[order(-b), .SD[b < 1][1L]]
}

identical(mtd1(), mtd2())
#[1] TRUE

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(mtd1(), mtd2(), times=3L)
```

timings:

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min       lq       mean   median        uq      max neval
 mtd1() 737.5113 754.3420 766.047900 771.1728 780.31620 789.4596     3
 mtd2()   1.6830   1.7687   3.118033   1.8544   3.83555   5.8167     3
```

Comment: Doesn't always work.  For example,  `identical(mtd1(), mtd2())` is `FALSE` after running  `DT[a == 3, b := .99]`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant if you do `DT <- stack` with `stack` as defined in the question, and then run `DT[a == 3, b := .99]` then  `identical(mtd1(), mtd2())` is `FALSE`

Comment: No the answer should not be `a==3` in that case because `b` is greater than 1 in row 4.

Comment: ah okok. let me fix b < 1

Comment: Probably better to test with e.g. `b=10*runif(M)`, since otherwise everything is less than 1 making the `b < 1` condition irrelevant.

Comment: thanks for the sharp catch. i have updated the solution.

Comment: I was hoping you'd find a similar solution which worked. Great improvement!

Comment: thats too many mistakes!...have fixed it by moving the `-` from before `order` to inside `order`